# How to order a string list based upon a reference list of string values

Tags: c#, regex

I have a List of strings in C#. It contains the following substrings somewhere in the middle of the strings within the list. The list is not ordered. I want to order this list, based upon the following entries in them:

```
Email
FirstName
LastName
Country
Province
Phone
Fax
```

in this order.

For example if the original list had the following entries:

```
The field Province required 5 letters
Wrong Email
Phone is required
FirstName should contain min of 5 letters
The field Fax requires 10 digits
Enter a valid LastName
Fax is required
The field Phone requires 10 digits
```

It needs to be sorted as follows:

```
Wrong Email
FirstName should contain min of 5 letters
Enter a valid LastName
The field Province required 5 letters
Phone is required
The field Phone requires 10 digits
Fax is required
The field Fax requires 10 digits
```

Thanks

Comment: If this is about correctly ordering validation output based on a sequence of form fields, I have the sinking feeling that you're going in the wrong direction.

Comment: I dont think you want/need regex for this - I would probably use list [of strings] and just reorder it programtically. Also, as a side note (and I didnt down vote you) - my first name contains 4 letters, this would frustrate me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be something like this.

```
var order = new List<string>()
{
    "Email",
    "FirstName",
    "LastName",
    "Country",
    "Province",
    "Phone",
    "Fax",
};

var lines = new List<string>()
{
    "The field Province required 5 letters",
    "Wrong Email",
    "Phone is required",
    "FirstName should contain min of 5 letters",
    "The field Fax requires 10 digits",
    "Enter a valid LastName",
    "Fax is required",
    "The field Phone requires 10 digits",
};

Func<string, int> calc = s => Regex.Matches(s, @"\w+").Cast<Match>()
                                .Select(m => m.Value)
                                .Max(x => order.IndexOf(x));

var result = lines.OrderBy(l => calc(l)).ToList();
```

You may need to fix this code if a line doesn't contain any keywords from your set...

*BTW: your question is not clear for a case like*

```
Wrong Email or Fax number
```